# Advice on setting up a site with front end registration

Tags: user-registration, front-end

I have been tasked with creating a site for a large audience, and many of the audience will require some sort of sign up. They may require certain account controls (visual things, like theme colours for colour blind people) but largely it will just be a way to monitor the use of the contact features (so users can monitor their previous interactions like a ticket system)

My question really is simply, where do I start? Is Wordpress the right tool for this job? If not, what is? If so, what methods should I be looking into to start the research going?

Sorry for the broadness of the question, but I feel a little lost at the moment.

Comment: As for the question is WP right for the job... what sort of things are you trying to do exactly? Knowing what functionality you need out of the site will help determine rather or not WP is right for the job

Comment: it is a site for people with learning difficulties. It is a very broad information site, with some customisable elements (colours, font size, appearance of help video/audio) and a trackable contact system, like a bug ticketing system.

Comment: I'm not so sure that wordpress is going to be the best choice for a site like this. I mean, you certainly could make it work, but I think I'd look into a different CMS. I'd think that something like Drupal might be a little bit better choice for something like the application you are describing. Oh, and all the registration stuff is already taken care of in that.

Comment: The problem with that is that I know wordpress pretty well, I can jimmy it to do most things. It's a little daunting to get into another CMS. Especially one without an active stackexchange site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's few months already and you probably have this solved by now but I'll try to do a little necromancing resume here anyway. We don't like unanswered questions right? ;)

There's a recent topic dealing with the front-end login & registration:
[Front-end Register Form](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7134/front-end-register-form)

You can change what WordPress displays to the users based on their capabilites by using the `current_user_can()` function.

There's also a topic about loading alternate CSS:
[How can I version the main CSS file?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/136/how-can-i-version-the-main-css-file)
Be sure to check related questions too.

By using `body_class()` or `post_class()` you can change the CSS class of html body (or post) depending on the logged user.

If those changes you want to achieve are intended to be more user based then role based then you can work with `update_user_meta()` and save some options in there.

*None of the above is hard to achieve. All mentioned functions are well documented.*

EDIT: Oh and the ticket system - You could use custom post types with front-end posting as a good starting point.