# Front end user creation form! How do you keep the user on the same page in event of error?

Tags: redirect, user-registration, front-end

I've recently tried to add a user registration form to the front end of my site and have used the following form code (based upon [this](http://digwp.com/2010/12/login-register-password-code) I discovered in an answer by [maugly](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/2110/maugly) in question [Front-end Register Form](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7134/front-end-register-form)) in a template file:

```
    <div id="tab2_login" class="tab_content_login" >
        <h3>Add a child</h3>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('wp-login.php?action=register', 'login_post') ?>" class="wp-user-form">
            <div class="username">
                <label for="user_login"><?php _e('Child Name'); ?>: </label>
                <input type="text" name="user_login" value="<?php echo esc_attr(stripslashes($user_login)); ?>" size="20" id="user_login" />
            </div>
            <div class="email">
                <input type="text" name="user_email" value="<?php echo esc_attr(stripslashes($user_email)); ?>" size="25" id="user_email" />
            </div>
            <div class="login_fields">
                <?php do_action('register_form'); ?>
                <input type="submit" name="user-submit" value="add child" class="user-submit" />
                <?php 

                $register = $_GET['register']; 


                if($register == true) { 

                    //now add it to the link database

                    echo '<p>User Added!</p>'; 

                } ?>

                <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>?register=true" />  

                <input type="hidden" name="user-cookie" value="1" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

The `redirect_to` attribute is set here to the requesting page which is all great when it works by triggering the if block to display an additional success message.

The question I have is when an error is detected in `wp-login.php` (such as the username is already in use) how do I get the redirect to come back to this page as opposed to the wp-login generated login box/error display? I can't see any obvious hook to grab hold of (although I've never used actions yet, so could be missing something!)

Help and guidance very much appreciated!

Ryan

Answer (score 1):

Hook into registration_errors (The WP Codex is woefully incomplete on this, but see links below).

Sorry this isn't more helpful -- the issue is a little more complex than it seems at the outset. I'll look into it more later.

Links:

- http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/registration_errors
- http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/10672
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/registration_errors and
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/register_post

Comment: hi there - are you saying adding a filter like: add_filter('registration_errors', 'myfunction', 10, 3); will let me define myfunction that sets a new redirect_to attribute? Is it possible to do this in a template file or do I need a plugin to use these hooks? Sorry for the newb questions!

Comment: :-) about as far as I got from your original link. My current thinking is that this seems a ballache! I reckon doing a ajax/jquery check into functions like username_exists() and email_exists() is the way to go...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you need to check if the username is already registered, and if so, redirect back to the register form ? or something.

I am thinking you need to use the auth_redirect() function in WP.
This isn't going to help you, but it's something I came up with to redirect users back to the previous page they were on after they log in, instead of going to the Dashboard as WP does when logging in.

```
function you_must_login() {
    global $post;

    if ( !is_single() ) // if not currently on a single post (can use any other conditional here of your choice)
    return;

    $post_ids = array( 188, 185, 171 ); // array of post IDs that force users to login before reading

    if ( in_array( (int) $post->ID, $post_ids ) && !is_user_logged_in() ) {
        auth_redirect(); // redirect to previous page after logging in
    }
}
```

Perhaps this can be of some use to you. I am pretty sure you may need to use auth_redirect though.

Comment: Thanks Jared. Certainly a basic and very handy tip, as many people will want to know this. I have reverted to using plugins for this sort of thing now simply because I am lazy and other people code much better than I!

Comment: haha, yeah, i know the feeling. laziness can be a hard thing to overcome. Hence why i made a custom post type that I use to just post code snippets instead of writing blog posts which explain them more in-depth haha.

Answer (score 0):

This redirects errors to the homepage. Put in functions.php

```
// block wordpress default login if error for extra security
function prevent_login_access() {
if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), '/wp-login') !== false) {
wp_redirect( home_url() );
}
}

add_action('init', 'prevent_login_access', 0);
```

For same page I'm not sure sorry- but with this you can redirect it to a custom error page or anything else.

Comment: But that wasn’t the question …