# custom registration form

Tags: plugins, themes, user-registration, front-end

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Front-end Register Form](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7134/front-end-register-form)

i like to create custom register form like http://www.bharatmatrimony.com/  this page in worpress ... i have searched many plugins no one helps me ...

How to do this any idea !

Comment: agreed - this is a duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Cimy User Extra Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cimy-user-extra-fields/) , its a plugin that lets you add extra user fields to the registration form.

or you can create your own custom registration page with your extra fields by following this great article http://www.cozmoslabs.com/2010/05/31/wordpress-user-registration-template-and-custom-user-profile-fields/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Profile Builder plugin](http://www.cozmoslabs.com/2011/04/12/wordpress-profile-builder-a-front-end-user-registration-login-and-edit-profile-plugin/)

It lets you customize your website by adding front-end forms for login, register and edit-profile through the use of shortcodes.